# Extract link from an element found by XPAth,using BrowserSessions, C# and Selenium drivers

Tags: c#, selenium, session, xpath

How do I extract a link's URL using XPath, I am using browser.Sessions, I want to extract it and use it somewhere-else.

Xpath of the element with url being`"//tbody/tr/td[1]/a"`

I have tried ...`FindXPath("//tbody/tr/td[1]/a").Text`

which gives me the inner text, InnerHTML, location and not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is usually stored in the `href` tag. So you can fetch the url using the `getAttribute` method.
You can do it like:

```
string url = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tbody/tr/td[1]/a")).GetAttribute("href");
```